# I have three different copies of same website in webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console

I transferred my blog from `blogger.com` to WordPress. Now my webmaster tools is having three copies of same website. One with `blogspot.com` that is redirecting to a new domain and one with www and one without www.

Is it normal? Should I keep it this way?

Like

1. `example.blogspot.com`
2. `example.com`
3. `www.example.com`

Comment: Yes, its normal to have many sites added to Webmaster Tools, Google recommends that you add all sites even through they may redirect, you then can tell Google the preferred one. A lot of webmasters now have 4 sites (`https://example.com`, `https://www.example.com`, `http://www.example` and `http://www.example.com`).

Comment: Whilst the end result might be the same website. The 3 URLs above are all _different_, which equates to potentially 3 _different_ websites.